# How to setup Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers

I got a dell PC for my 17th birthday. It came with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and I am very new to Linux and Ubuntu and I don't know how to setup Ubuntu once I have installed it.
If someone can help me that would be awesome, thank you.

Comment: Updates should be offered automatically, there is usually no need to install drivers. Check out [Ubuntu Manual](https://ubuntu-manual.org/) for more info.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Same here. I have a brand new Dell Inspiron 3000 (3567). It arrived with Ubuntu 16.04 on it. It's been put aside for a week because I didn't know what to do with it. This morning I started it up and it kept losing wifi connection (none of my other machines do).

So I clicked on search your computer, typed in "updates", clicked on "Software updater" and a window opened checking for updates. It found loads and I clicked to install them.  I thought all the updates took longer to install than Windows 7 ever did and at first it still kept losing connection during the update process. But I persisted and after a while my wifi stayed connected and the updates continued.

All updates have now been installed and I haven't lost wifi connection since.

Comment: Nice, what a coincident I got the same pc as you. I will update Ubuntu, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the main question is answered; however, factory_image.iso will be the master CD image, should you need to re-install.

Personally, I used to keep installation CDs until I realised I never ever wanted to revert to an ancient image; it's easier to download a fresh one.

You should keep at least one spare bootable thing, be it a CD, a flash drive, external HDD or whatever, or you may end up having to borrow a PC to make one somewhen!

So I'd recommend installing a CD-Writer (eg `k3b`) & making the CD for now, or copying to USB stick, just as backup while you learn. The simplest is to stick in a spare USB stick (capacity larger than size of .iso file) & copy it from a terminal - the 'how' has been heavily covered on here :) but don't just copy it with the mouse, that doesn't work.